# FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, excel

Im trying to parse a XLSM workbook,

I have linked using:

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;       //microsoft Excel 16 object in dependencies-> COM tab
```

Exception:

```cs
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=TrafficDataPrep
  StackTrace:
   at TrafficDataPrep.XLSMReader.ReadXLSM() in C:...Program.cs:line 287
   at TrafficDataPrep.SplitFiles.Main() in C:...Program.cs:line 27
```

And in Dependencies > addReference > COM I added a reference to Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Which should support my excel version, my excel version is `16.0.12527.21296`

Followed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55fe7d16-998b-4c43-9746-45ff35310158/office-2016-interop-assemblies?forum=exceldev) to link the assembly for Excel.

Any ideas why its still throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my .NET version was archaic. Updating to .NET 5 fixed the issue.

Comment: I use .NET 7 and it's not fixed. 
IMHO, the issue is (usually) not related to .NET version.